# Why is the UI not updated when I change an object reference in an interval and the change detection is onPush?

Tags: angular

Example:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-ex3-component-a",
    templateUrl: "./ex3-component-a.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./ex3-component-a.component.scss"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Ex3ComponentAComponent implements OnInit
{
    public config = {title: "Initial title."};

    public interval: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit(): void
    {
    }

    public changeTitle()
    {
        if (this.interval)
        {
            this.interval.unsubscribe();
            this.interval = null;
            return;
        }

        this.interval = interval(300)
        .pipe(
            map(() => ({...this.config, title: `From A (${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)})`})),
            tap((newConfig) => this.config = newConfig),
            tap(() => console.log(this.config.title))
        ).subscribe();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>config.title={{config.title}}</p>
<button (click)="changeTitle()">{{interval ? "Stop" : "Start changing"}}</button>
```

What happens:

- every 300 ms a new value is displayed in the console
- the UI only changes when I stop the interval
- if i set the interval to for example to 3 seconds, the same happens

I expect the UI to be updated as well as the console - but its not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you use`onPush`, angular is looking for changes on `Input` parameters.

For more: [onpush-change-detection-how-it-works](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)

You can detect the changes manually (that's the recommended way) like this:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)

this.interval = interval(300)
        .pipe(
            map(() => ({...this.config, title: `From A (${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)})`}))
        ).subscribe(newConfig => {
             this.config = newConfig;
             this.cdr.detectChanges();
             console.log(this.config.title);
         });
```

- Be aware that the code is not tested, maybe it has some typo's, but the main idea is correct.

Comment: the dependency is "ChangeDetectorRef" from @angular/core, thanks for your fast answer!